# Difference between toString() methods of CharSequence Interface and Object class

Tags: java

What is the real difference between the `toString()` method in `CharSequence` interface and `toString()` method in `Object` class?

I know that `String` class by default implements `CharSequence` and extends `Object` class.

But does `String` class give implementation to `toString()` from `CharSequence`?If so then Which virsion of `toString()` gets invoked when we print the `String`?

Comment: Try looking at the source code of `String.toString()`.

Comment: No ! I just wanna say that we have a toString() given by Object class in our String class! Also we have another toString() via CharSequence(since String implements CharSequence)! Ofcourse String class would have been given an implementation of the abstract method toString() of CharSequence! So what about that when we print String objects?Which one is invoked? And why? because both methods have same prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is defined in the `CharSequence` interface, it is not implemented. This is done to add relevant documentation about the requirements that implementations of `CharSequence` need to follow.

Specifically (Java 8 Update 141), the definition in `CharSequence` is:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the same
>  * order as this sequence.  The length of the string will be the length of
>  * this sequence.
>  *
>  * @return  a string consisting of exactly this sequence of characters
>  */
> public String toString();
> ```

This describes how `toString()` must behave for `CharSequence` implementations.

Contrast this with the javadoc in `Object`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>  * {@code toString} method returns a string that
>  * "textually represents" this object. The result should
>  * be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a
>  * person to read.
>  * It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>  * <p>
>  * The {@code toString} method for class {@code Object}
>  * returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>  * object is an instance, the at-sign character `{@code @}', and
>  * the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
>  * object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
>  * value of:
>  * <blockquote>
>  * <pre>
>  * getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
>  * </pre></blockquote>
>  *
>  * @return  a string representation of the object.
>  */
> public String toString()
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From your question "Which one is invoked?", it sounds as if you think there are two separate `toString` methods: one from `CharSequence` and one from `Object`. That is not the case. In Java, a method with the same name is the same method, regardless of whether it implements a method from one, two or many interfaces.

For instance:

```
interface I1 {
    int foo();
}
interface I2 {
    int foo();
}
class C implements I1, I2 {
    int foo() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

In Java, there is only one method `foo()` irrespective of whether it comes via interace I1 or I2. Contrast this with C#, where you can give two different implementations of `foo()`: one for each interface.

Looking specifically at your question, when you write a class that implements `CharSequence` you are meant to override the `toString` method. However, the only thing that makes you do that is the documentation. If you don't override it, you'll inherit `Object.toString`. If you do override it, you'll override the one and only one `toString` method, since as I've shown above, `Object.toString` and `CharSequence.toString` are not different.

Comment: It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If there are tow methods with the same signature in super class and super interface, the sub class will inherit the one from super class and use it to override the one inherit from super interface.
You can refer to this demo.

```
    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
            subClass.printA();  // I inherit from SuperClass
            subClass.printB();  // I inherit from SuperClass
        }
    }


    class SuperClass{
        public void printA(){
            System.out.println("I inherit from SuperClass");
        }

        public void printB(){
            System.out.println("I inherit from SuperClass");
        }
    }

    interface SuperInterface{
        public default void printA(){
            System.out.println("I inherit from SuperInterface");
        };

        void printB();
    }

    class SubClass extends SuperClass implements SuperInterface{
        // No need to override printB() of SuperInterface, 
        // as already inherited one from SuperClass
    }
```